# Scala (x is not a member of the class)

Tags: scala, int, boolean

So there's an object with three int values. Lets call this object blue. I am trying to make a boolean method that returns true if the value of the Int in blue is valid. Each Int is has a different restriction on it. This method is called isBlueValid

For example, blue is made of Ints x, y, z.
The value of x needs to be between 10 and 20 while the value of y and z needs to be between 30 and 50.

So here is my code example

```
case class Blue(x : Int, y : Int, z : Int){
      def isValidBlue(blue: Blue) : Boolean = {
           if(Blue.x > ... && Blue.x <....... &&Blue.y <...............)
                    true
           else
                    false
```

But each time I try to run the method it keeps saying x is not a member of Blue and y is not a member of Blue and z is not a member of Blue.

Help?

Comment: Can you post a more complete example that demonstrates the problem? Specifically the function and class in question.

Comment: Rather than make us guess, post code.

Comment: Your if is unnecessary. `if (<bool-expression>) true else false` is the same as `<bool-expression>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** : You should replace `Blue.x` with `this.x` or just `x`. `Blue.x` is trying to call a method or val from the case class's companion object, and not `this` instance.

---

It *seems* like you want something like this:

```
case class Blue(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) {
    def isValid: Boolean = ((x < 21 && x > 9) && (y > 29 && y < 51) && (z > 0)) // filled in z condition with whatever
}
```

`if(..) true else false` is redundant when returning a `Boolean`, since the `if` condition returns the same `Boolean` value.

```
scala> val test = Blue(1,2,3)
scala> test.isValid
res0: Boolean = false

scala> val test = Blue(10,30,3)
scala> test.isValid
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: It gave an error in that there is not enough arguments, but after I made it take no arguments it works perfectly. Thanks!